# How to protect culturally bald people from sunburn?

Tags: culture, environment, health

What are some ways that people in a culture where head shaving is common practice could protect themselves from sunburn and other natural elements?

Comment: Assuming you live in a populated area, just go outside and look around.  Lots of bald people out there, either natural or cultural.

Comment: I shave my head for 20 years already, and only got sunburn on the very first day, when my head skin was pale. Then it simply gets tanned.

Comment: Only go out at night?

Comment: Use sunblock like any other bald person? Unless you mean a different time period, this seems like the most obvious answer...

Comment: A Dyson sphere would be the only true answer

Comment: Technology level? Does the culture have access to sunscreen?

Comment: Melatonin - make them black.

Comment: I read this as "How to protect culturally *bad* people from sunburn?" and thought this was a very odd world to build indeed!

Comment: @HopelessN00b. Melatonin would make them sleepy.  Melanin would make them black LOL

Answer (score 85):

They could wear a hat, or other head covering.

Hats are a nifty invention that can protect a head from the sun, or insulate it from the cold depending on construction and configuration. There are even specialized hats that can protect the head from falling debris or small arms fire.

A towel will work well enough in a pinch, which is why you should never leave home without one.

Comment: For quite a long time, in Europe and in other countries belonging to the European culture, it was _unthinkable_ for a man to go out in public with his head bare. Look at old (pre-1950) movies and pay attention at how careful are the men with their hats or caps and how they will _always_ put their hats or caps on when in public.

Comment: @AlexP, Yep.  "Get your hat." was code for we're going out.

Comment: @AlexP, somehow that had never struck home to me, but it makes sense—and also explains the extreme reactions depicted in very old comic strips when a man's hat blows off his head.  Like having your pants fall down.

Comment: Yes, the abolition of hats was effectively a result of the haircare products industry combined with the "cult of youth" and the rising cultural importance of sport.

Comment: @AlexP, also in XVI-XVII it was unthinkable in Europe (for upper classed person)  to be out of your bedroom without fancy powdered wig.

Comment: @user28434: *Western* Europe. Wigs were not used in central and eastern Europe; at least, not by men.

Comment: @AlexP, well yeah, I always forget that central and eastern Europe is still considered Europe.

Comment: Currently, there are organizations which enforce the requirement that one wear their hat at all times while outside (US Marine Corps comes immediately to mind) in uniform, so cultural hat requirements are not just the stuff of past generations.

Comment: And of course wearing the towel will immediately signal you're a frood who really knows where their towel is.

Comment: It's also interesting to consider what culture might arise from the habitual wearing of headgear. Various social classes could have different forms of hats to denote status or career.

Comment: So you're saying a hat is a reverse thermos?

Answer (score 24):

other ideas

**Parasol.**

[source](https://i.pinimg.com/736x/ea/49/bc/ea49bc8bf517b3af2f1a211883f3f1da.jpg)
[image: bald lady with parasol]

**Live animal.**
[image: lady with cat for hat]

**Stuff you need.**
[image: guy with huge load of hay on head]

Comment: I really hope he goes for either 2) or 3)

Comment: #1 makes me wonder if a whole-scalp tattoo might help.

Comment: @T.E.D. There was a documentary I watched at one point where a woman had an extreme "sun allergy," or [porphyria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porphyria#Triggers) of the skin. She had every part of her body tattooed, and the tattoos protected her from the blisters that would be caused. That being said, I am unsure if they would protect from sunburn.

Comment: @jkelm My wife has porphyria. The nature of her condition seems to prevent her from tanning or burning, only blistering. Tattooed skin is also affected, which leads me to think the woman in that documentary was probably more of a performance artist than a credible dermatological practitioner :\

Comment: Para-sol, it literally means "anti-sun". +1.

Comment: @Ivan - I sympathize with your wife. I don't have porphyria, but I do have skin like snow and fiery red hair. I usually skip burning and go straight to blisters, and one of my kids was unlucky enough to inherit that. As a result, I strongly consider the sun to be my mortal enemy.

Answer (score 16):

**Be Black**

By having an appropriate amount of melanin in their skin they can greatly reduce their vulnerability to sunburns.

Most other exposure issues are solvable by having enough to eat and drink. If you are squeamish about huddling, shivering and sweating:

**Have the sense to come in out of the rain**

Houses are a common invention to limit natural elements' intrusion into human lives. When combined with clothes we can live comfortably pretty much anywhere on Earth.

Comment: Let's hear it for the obvious yet untrue. Black folk can sunburn. http://www.ebony.com/wellness-empowerment/doctors-orders-yes-black-people-do-get-sunburn-405#axzz4rx9dYjdY

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast He still has a point though, just in the way that a bullet proof vest is actually just bullet *resistant*

Comment: @GrinningX, TheoclesofSaturn check the edit time stamp. I toned down the answer to address the criticism.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt , WhatRoughBeast - My apologies, I should have checked the edit.  I'll delete my comment as non-contributing then.

Answer (score 11):

You don't specify level of technology or anything useful about this culture, so I can really only give a few basic answers that all predate the era of modern sunscreens.

1. **Hat.** Preferably broad brimmed, as this will also shade the eyes. A tall stovepipe hat can also be used to keep a small flask or perhaps a derringer. Never know when those might come in handy!
2. **Scarf / turban / kerchief.** Easy to use, plus they can be put to other uses as well.
3. **Wig.** A must at court. Looks dandy on the town!
4. **Sunscreen.** Non-permanent, but does leave the shaved head visible so you can walk like an Egyptian.
5. **Ancient resources.** Speaking of Egyptians, we moderns aren't the first to worry about sun exposure! They apparently used some concoction of rice and jasmine.  Zinc oxide has also long been known to medicine and protects against UVA & B.

Comment: "Sunscreen" seems such an obvious answer that I find it amazing it didn't pop up until the fourth option of the fourth-ranked answer.

Comment: Speaking of the ancient egyptians they shaved their heads AND wore wigs. Shaving your head was believed to make the gods look favorably upon you, but hairstyles were big fashion so most people did both by shaving then wearing a styled wig. the rich had wigs made of hair, the less wealth made due with animal hair and the poor made do with straw wigs.

Comment: T.E.D. --- sunscreen probably has not been mentioned because the OQ doesn't really indicate a time frame or technology level. It is a quite modern invention, really. I was kind of surprised to learn that effective sunscreens only date to the late 1930s or early 1940s.

Answer (score 4):

**Head <strike>tattoos</strike> paint**.

[image]

<strike>If you google for head tattoo, you will find many more
(and very beautiful) tattoos for the head. And yes,
if you use specific paint, the resistance against ultraviolet
radiation will increase drastically.</strike>

ADDITION: user151841 pointed out that tattoos cannot protect against sunburn
because a sunburn burns only the epidermis, the topmost layer of the skin which is continually shed. So the other option is using paint directly on the skin, but this means it must be renewed each day. Metallic paint should give a very good protection.

**Acclimatization**

You simply are most of the time out. The sun is normally **not**
burning like fire from one day after another, but increases strength
gradually. People get sunburn because they are inside buildings until
the sun is really strong and *then* go out and wonder why their skin
get burned.

**Siesta**

Simply avoid being outside when the sun is the strongest.

Comment: Tattoos cannot protect against sunburn. Sunburn is the burning of the epidermis, the outermost layer of skin, which sheds continuously http://clinuvel.com/science-of-skin/skin-sun/sunburn . This is why sunburned skin peels away. If tattoos were put into the epidermis, they would come off over weeks. Tattoos rather are injected into the next layer down, the dermis: http://www.popsci.com/science/article/2013-06/fyi-what-makes-tattoos-permanent . So a layer of pigment, no matter how opaque, can protect the epidermis above it.

Comment: However, tattoos do protect against [porphyria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porphyria#Triggers) of the skin, which is why some people believe they would help with sunburn.

Comment: @user151841 Thanks for pointing it out, I adjusted the answer accordingly.

Comment: @ThorstenS. upvote redeemed : )

Answer (score 4):

Answer: the Oxygen molecule O<sub>3</sub>, known as Ozone.

I live in New Zealand and between us and the Australians we have a high level of UV compared to other places in the world.    I get sunburned through my clothes, and I can get sunburned on a cloudy day.

Some of this is because of the Ozone hole over the antarctic, allowing more ulta-violet in sunlight to come though.

So your planet could have a naturally higher level of ozone, or could be **actively adding ozone to the atmosphere** somehow.

Perhaps there are a lot of shorelines, because Ozone is generated by wave action.  Or a heap of electrical activity, again oxygen is converted to ozone in proximity of electrical discharges.

Ozone is damaged by chloroflorocarbons, aka CFCs, that were used in spray cans for years, as well as refrigerents like Freon and fire suppressent like Halon.  Your planet should never have any of this.

Links:

- More on Ozone at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozone)
- ENZ website, specifically [But How Pleasant Is The Sunshine?](https://www.enz.org/new-zealand-sunshine.html)
- [NZ has the highest skin cancer rates in the world](https://www.sciencelearn.org.nz/resources/1329-nz-skin-cancer-statistics) and to quote "The strength of the UV radiation that New Zealand receives – our UV levels are 40% higher during summer than at corresponding latitudes in the northern hemisphere (NIWA research)."  and "The low ozone levels – the ozone layer absorbs a good deal of UVB ultraviolet light from the Sun. Any decrease in the ozone layer (such as the ‘ozone hole’ over Antarctica) is expected to increase surface UVB levels. "

Comment: Downside to this suggestion is that its a whole-planet solution, and its not "people protecting themselves" its the entire culture protecting all of its people together, which may not fit your need.

Comment: Wow, the things you learn. The ozone hole over the Antarctic somehow affects Australia/New Zealand, um no. Ozone depletion is a world-wide phenomenon, and on the order of 6-9% since 1960. Ozone hole over Antarctica is unrelated. Ground level UV does not migrate up to the Ozone layer, it decomposes more rapidly than that.

Comment: "[isotope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotope)" refers to single atoms with different numbers of neutrons.  O3's only real connection to elemental oxygen would be that it's triatomic homonuclear oxygen.

Comment: @Kevin good point - fixed.

Comment: @GaryWalker - *What are you talking about?* UV is a wavelength of light. How would "ground level UV" *migrate* up to the Ozone layer? That's not how it works. The Ozone layer absorbs UV light. What makes it to the surface is what makes it there. It's not a gas which attenuates up into the atmosphere and definitely doesn't decompose. UV light works just like visible light. It can be: transmitted; reflected; absorbed (or a combination of the three).

Comment: @Criggie - Aren't you glad the [Ozone layer appears to be fixing itself](http://news.nationalgeographic.com/2016/06/antarctic-ozone-hole-healing-fingerprints/).

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 -- brain glitch, typed ground level UV instead of ground level ozone.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you have many answers that say "hat" but it's silly to think that you didn't also come up with that one on your own. Nevertheless, those answers seem to be well received, huzzah! I'll put a hat on right now in celebration.

Provided below are a few more possibilities. These are a little more 'outside the box.' I will also include links, unlike many of the "hat" answers.  I was previously advised to include links, after all, and am unsure if the hat answers are reliable as result.

I will warn you, it is possible that the links I provide may, some day, expire. I am not trying to go on and on, here, merely trying to find that perfect balance of an interesting answer, not too long, not too short, including links, but only the right *kinds* of links, and essential details.

With that said, finding the *correct answer* appears to be down to democracy and dealer's choice. Good thing you didn't ask about climate change. Here in the United States there is a 30% chance you would end up with something ridiculous.

On to the risk of sunburn (and skin cancer) for bald people.

**Answer 1.** They could evolve. This seems to be how many species have adapted to a lack of hats. [Here is a link](http://evolution.berkeley.edu/evolibrary/news/140305_skincolor) on how evolution is thought to protect us against the sun. You did not specify the time length required in your question. Hats will help in the immediate moment, but evolution is a better long term fix.

**Answer 2.** They could stay in the shade, or only go out at night. [Here is a link](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3071354/) showing that those who work the night shift have a 15% reduced risk of melanoma. Not bad. Make your race nocturnal and bald. This would protect against sunburn as well.

**Answer 3.** They could convince their government to geoengineer the planet to reflect UV rays. [Here is a link](https://phys.org/news/2016-12-mitigating-geoengineering-aerosols-cool-planet.html) describing geoengineering to reflect sunlight, a similar concept, but not tailored to bald people. Still, you can adapt it to your scenario.

**Answer 4.** They could decide to walk with their hands on their heads. Sound silly? Perhaps. But you may remember when [the chicken dance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AslZqfnNJwY) was all the rage. If you can convince an auditorium full of human beings to do the chicken dance, I think you can convince bald human beings to walk with their hands on their heads. This particular answer also helps protect bald people's scalps from rain.

People also like pictures, so here is a nice hat:
[image]

And lastly, please read the above as meant in good fun, and as a suggestion to not take anything on the internet too seriously.

Comment: Seems like it would be pointless to go through the trouble to shave to expose your scalp for religious reasons, and then put a hat on.

Answer (score 3):

Hardly a civilization-wide issue.

I have been shaving my head for many years. I am a Mediterranean white kind of person. My scalp enjoys some fresh air, but if the sun shines too brightly I put a hat on to prevent sunburn. Which is not a problem as I like hats very much and I live in an infamously sunlight-deprived country. Other people may have different preferences, or be blessed by lots of melanin in their skin.

Now, you know what could be interesting with reference to your world setting? What if hats were seen as immoral, sinful or illegal?

Update: TIL that ancient Egyptians used to shave their heads (beards) and put wigs on to cover their scalp (chin). This was a necessity in order to prevent lice infestations and  a very common custom amongst the free, but not amongst the slaves, who were in fact forbidden from shaving.

Comment: So are you suggesting that in this culture covering yourself is immoral instead of the opposite? I'm not sure if you mean to go that far with it, but a nudist culture might not be what OP had in mind.

Comment: Just a thought experiment, more of a suggestion than anything. In an environment which requires covering your head for health reasons, you could easily find a superstition/religion rule that forbids to do so easily.

Dunno, allow a "holy parasol" as the only way to get shelter from the sun?

Answer (score 2):

Make the sun go out, or move the home planet away from the sun.

Or, hats. Am I just a grump today? This question seems pretty silly.

Or! A giant orbiting opaque structure that blocks sunlight (an "earth hat").

But: hats.

Ooo! Breed bats to hover over people who are out in the sun. Or hummingbirds. But then they'd need something to keep from getting covered with poo.

Ya know what rhymes with "bat"?

Comment: I think you're just a grump today. From a certain point of view, _all_ questions are silly. Ya know what rhymes with "be rice"? :-)

Comment: @wizzwizz4: Be lice?  Be mice?  That doesn't sound very nice.  :P

Comment: I do apologize for being so hatful. I shall certainly try to cap my snark in the future! As thoughtful people are ad-visor-ing me to do.

Answer (score 2):

One answer not mentioned is to do what some animals do: roll through the mud, and protect your skin that way.

Whether that's going to be cultured acceptable in the world you're creating is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

**Im going to aggregate some here:**

- **Hats:** obviously, from ball caps to stetsons to rice farmer hats. Straightforward logic; if your head is getting burned by the sun put something on it.
- **Wraps:** Heads getting burned, wrap it in cloth (turbens, hajibs, bandanas etc.)
- **Be Black:** could be a natural evolution that they evolve their skin to protect itself naturally.
- **Sunblocks:** either natural dirts/muds or concoctions of herbs and chemicals.
- **Dead Animal:** Neolithic humanoids would wear animal hides to protect against exposure, same concept.
- **Wigs!:** the ancient Egyptions actually did practice head shaving because of lice and would replace their hair with wigs which could be disposed of or cleansed of the lice.

Honestly its the unique environmental conditions that you didnt mention that would ultimately affect the outcome the most.

Like if it rains diamonds maybe a hard hat would be the outcome over say a scarf.

Comment: Gotta say that live animal seems so much more interesting than dead animal.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what the setting is, but if you want to take it to an extreme everybody could live either underground or indoors in giant glass geodesic domes (like in Logan's Run) to give the feeling of being outside.

The glass should have UVA/UVB protection-- this is typical for any quality home window tint kit.